# Variable dentro de función no se cambia los datos, ¿por qué?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo este código en Node.js y cuando lo ejecuto el segundo `console.log(db.hello)` me sale vacío, como si la función no se hubiera ejecutado, pero en cambio a dentro de `read()` sí me va. Me gustaría saber por qué.

Tengo otro archivo llamado `db.json` donde tengo un `json` básico para probar. Es algo como esto:

```
{"hello": "hello"}
```

Y aquí el otro código de JavaScript:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const file = "./db.json"
var db = {}
function read(f, call){
  fs.readFile(f, "utf8", (err, data) =>{
    var s = err
    call(s, JSON.parse(data))
  })
}
read(file, (err, data) =>{
  if(err) throw err
  db = data
  console.log(db.hello)
})
console.log(db)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es por el modelo de eventos y funciones de Javascript. Por si te resulta mas familiar, cada llamada a `fs.readFile( )` es equivalente a una llamada AJAX en el lado cliente: **no** es síncrona, sino que la función pasada como argumento (en tu caso, la función anónima) es llamada **al completarse la petición**.

La secuencia de acciones que ocurre en el código que muestras es:

1. Llamas a tu función `read( )`. Aquí, estableces una función de respuesta ante el evento `fin-de-lectura-del-archivo`.
2. Se ejecuta el `console.log( )` en el código principal.
3. En algún momento, se llamará a tu función anónima. **Está garantizado** que dicha llamada será realizada **después** de que todo tu código *secuencial* se ejecute.
4. Se ejecuta el `console.log( )` **dentro** de tu manejador de eventos (tu función flecha).

Si quieres que el `console.log( )` externo muestre algo, puedes usar [`fs.readFileSync( )`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options).

Información adicional: [Modelo de concurrencia y loop de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), en la MDN.

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente es por la esencia del entorno de ejecución de JS que es asíncrono, es decir, que ejecuta cierto código pero la respuesta se retorna después, vaya, no es secuencial como en otros lenguajes de programación.

La siguiente liga te servirá para entender como funcionan los entornos de ejecución de javascript (navegadores y nodejs):
[Ejemplo del event loop](http://latentflip.com/loupe/)